# Unity has become a complete mess after installation of Pantheon

Tags: unity

After I installed Pantheon, my unity desktop is sometimes showing only black screen and the launcher and sometimes it is showing only wallpaper and launcher. I am not able too see the desktop icons. Also, even after purging pantheon ppa panteon still remains there. My other DE's like Cinnamon and KDE are working fine. Please help!

Comment: Please help me my problem is not being solved

Answer (score 1):

Today I ran into a similar trouble, and here's what helped me restore my desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get remove elementary*
```

Comment: You should probably reboot after that too.

Comment: And follow with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` in case the ppa replaced other packages with it's own packages of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the package not just the ppa

Reason:when you remove a ppa it doesn't remove the packages that you got from it

Comment: How do I do that?